# Linkextractor in Scrapy, pagination and 2 depth link

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to understand how the linkextractor is working in Scrapy.
What I am trying to accomplish:

- Follow pagination on start page
- Search URLs and scan all links in a pattern
- In the found links pages, follow another link on that page matching a pattern and scrap that page

My code:

```
class ToScrapeMyspider(CrawlSpider):
    name            = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["myspider.com"]
    start_urls      = ["www.myspider.com/category.php?k=766"]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//link[@rel="next"]/a'), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/product.php?p=\d+$"), callback='parse_spider')
)

    def parse_spider(self, response):
        Request(allow=r"/product.php?e=\d+$",callback=self.parse_spider2)

    def parse_spider2(self, response):
        #EXTRACT AND PARSE DATA HERE ETC (IS WORKING)
```

My links from pagination look like:

```
<link rel="next" href="https://myspider.com/category.php?k=766&amp;amp;s=100" >
```

First I get an error from restrict_xpaths

```
'str' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

But I guess I have screwed things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally working:

```
rules = (
          Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@rel="next"]',)), follow=True),
          Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('product\.php', )), callback='parse_sider'),
)


BASE_URL = 'https://myspider.com/'

def parse_spy(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//li[@id="id"]/a/@href').extract()
    for link in links:
        absolute_url = self.BASE_URL + link
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_spider2)
```

Comment: `response.urljoin(link)` is a more general solution to contextualizing relative urls.